# Why is the call to Php program via AJAX returning Blank in regard to the dynamic data only

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

1st, I am new to this forum.

I am using AJAX to call a Php program on the server that fetches data, based on query sent to it via the client. However, for some strange reason the AJAX return is not returning the dynamic part of the results, that is part created by the Php MySQL call!

And I have checked the Php page that AJAX is calling and when called by itself it shows that it is working A OK!

You can see the sample Php code being called here:

https://www.anoox.com/news/my_notes_fetch.php?val=Verisign2

as you see it does display the (sample) results just fine.

However, this (sample) result is missing when sent back to the client via AJAX, as you can see here:

https://www.anoox.com/news/my_notes_test.php1

ATTN: start typing into the above Textarea field: Verisign

As you will see Php program is called OK via the AJAX in that page, and data is returned OK from Php to that page, but the dynamic parts of the data is missing!

What is going on here?
FYI, I have lots of experience with AJAX and have never ran into this problem before!

Thanx,
Dean

Comment: I see no difference in the returned data between the two links ... both contains zeeroo "dynamic" data - you may want to fix the second link and get rid of the stray `1` after `.php` ... although, preferably, you should post a minimal complete verifiable example of code in the question itself

Comment: Oh that's ugly ... type `verisi` - get an alert - type `gn` `[backspace]` `[backspace]` `gn` (to once again trigger 6th key up) and voilà - it works ... your JS logic is, how you say, inelegant